# Database for substring search

Tags: sql, database, nosql, substring

1. This is **not** full text search!

I have approximately 1 billion of rows, the core column is a string with medium length of 13 chars and I want to search with a substring as filter in **any** positions (left, right, middle) for all occurrences.
Would be great if select would work in milliseconds :)

What DB/engine would work for this task, currently looking at pg_trgm extension for postgres,

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a database for this.
Databases don't do sub-string matches from their index very efficiently in any case.

Here is some code.

```
string search;  //This is the sub-string you are searching for
string* data = new string[1000000000]; //Allocate and populate a billion strings

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(data[i].find(search, 0) != std::string::npos);
    cout << data[i] << endl;
}
```

Is it hard to imagine a faster solution unless you switch to assembler code.

Best answer probably also depends on where the data is (on disk, in RAM, etc..), if you want an exact match or maybe with word stemming, your preferred programming language and how often the data changes. For example, if you have a finite set of search strings then Aho–Corasick algorithm might work?

Comment: I actually want a db because of data structure + currently the data is stored in db (not a big problem for migration). Dump is updating every month by only inserting new data